# Perl - a way to run a script multiple time and append output files

Tags: perl, append

I would like to run a perl script multiple times and append output files in a file.

Let's say I have a perl script (sparc_sub.pl) that generate an output file, sparc_sub.output. I would like to run it multiple times. In every time run, it retunes the same output file (sparc_sub.output), but the content is different.

I know '>>' is the sign if I would like to append to the end of the file, so I used the sign to open the output files in a loop. However, the output file, sparc_sub.output always stores the result of the last run. (not appending)

Any help is appreciated.

sparc_top.pl

```
use strict;
use Math::BigInt;
use 5.010;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $s;
my $done=3;
my $script="sparc_sub.pl";
my @output; 
my $filename ='sparc_sub.output';

for ($s=0; $s < $done; $s++) {
    system('perl',$script)==0 or die "failed to execute $script: \$?=$?";
    open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're opening the file and immediately closing it without writing anything to it. You need to modify the code that actually writes to the file!

Comment: note that you should put your `open` of the file before your `for()` loop, and the `close` after it. This opens the file once, instead of on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You need to show us the part of `sparc_sub.pl` that opens the file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opened the file and then immediately closed it without even writing anything to it.

```
open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "this data goes to file";
close $fh;
```

---

> I have a perl script `sparc_sub.pl` that generate an output file, `sparc_sub.output`

So with each run the same file will be generated. I think you want to create a new file which will keep appending the data from `sparc_sub.output`. If that's the case then do below.

```
open(my $fh2, '>>', 'all_outputs') or die "Could not open file 'all_outputs' $!";

for ($s=0; $s < $done; $s++) {
    system('perl',$script)==0 or die "failed to execute $script: \$?=$?";
    #sparc_sub.output has been generated. 
    #Now take the data from this file and append it to a final file
    open(my $fh, '<', 'sparc_sub.output') or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    my @data = <$fh>;
    print $fh2 @data;
}
```

Now `all_outputs` file contains the data from `sparc_sub.output` file which was generated multiple times in the loop.

Comment: While true, it looks like the child script is doing the file operations, so the real answer is probably to change to append mode there.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the `open` of the write handle outside of the `for()` loop in this case, instead of opening/closing on each iteration.